# mysql pool.getConnection fails breaks the code

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

im new to nodejs so bare with me  , im trying to to some connection heavy task like a game server
i have a mysql poll and a function `create_game` which will use the poll to get a new connection

so i noticed sometimes the nodejs will stop working for no reason , i traced to problem in `create_game` function by putting numbers on each line like

```
 console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} :1 `);
 console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : 2 `);
```

to see which line is breaking my code

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 20 ,
    host            : myEnv.parsed.DB_HOST,
    user            : myEnv.parsed.DB_USERNAME,
    password        : myEnv.parsed.DB_PASSWORD,
    database        : myEnv.parsed.DB_DATABASE
});





function create_game( debug_id ) {

    console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : 1 `);

    let promise =  new Promise(function(resolve , reject ) {
    
        console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : 2 `);

        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : 3 `);
            if (err) {
                console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : 3E `);
                reject(err.sqlMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                connection.beginTransaction(function (err) { 
                
                  /// do stufff 

                 console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : success `);


                });

            }

        });
    })

    .then(function (res) {

        consoleLog('create success');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        consoleLog('///////////ERROR///////////');
        consoleLog(error);

     });

}
```

this is what i got in the console

```
 @-> 7 : 1
 @-> 7 : 2
 @-> 7 : 3
 @-> 7 : 4
 @-> 7 : 5
 @-> 7 : 6
 @-> 7 : 7
 @-> 7 : 8
 @-> 7 : 9
 @-> 7 : 10
 @-> 7 : 11
 @-> 7 : 12
 @-> 7 : success

 @-> 8 : 1
 @-> 8 : 2
```

so based on the output it seems `pool.getConnection` is failing i assume becuz it hit the `connectionLimit : 20` at that point

so what im doing wrong ? why the code breaks .. i mean i do have a code to handle `pool.getConnection` fail in here so why im not getting `3` and `3E` output  ?

```
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : 3 `);
            if (err) {
                console.log(` @-> ${debug_id} : 3E `);
                reject(err.sqlMessage);
            }
```

i still see the socket connections in terminal being made so the node script still works ... but all the database related operations will stop working after this without any error or output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more information. You have not mentioned what mysql library you are using? The logs you are showing do not match the code. i.e. where are logs `4-12`?

So I am assuming you are using [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

An observation from the code that you have shown which could be a possible cause of your problem is that when you take a connection from the pool, you also need to release it back. You haven't shown that you are releasing the connection so I can only assume that you are not.

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM sometable', function (error, results, fields) {
    // When done with the connection, release it.
    connection.release();

    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
  });
});
```

See https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

If you do not release the connection, you will use up all connections in the pool and the other requests for a connection will be queued and it would exhibit the behavior that you are describing.

On a side, you can also query directly on the pool which will handle releasing connections back to the pool once finished. That may not be a suitable use case for above as it looks like you are using the connection as part of a transaction - where you do need a reference to the underlying connection.

Comment: thanx , im using `mysqljs/mysql` , i deleted  `logs 4-12` to keep the code simple as problem was occurring  on log 2-3  , i just put ` /// do stufff  ` in their place .... good point on connection release i wasn't releasing the connection and thats probably is cuzing the problem .... but still the question remains .... why the error argument on `pool.getConnection` wasn't catching the error  ?

Comment: Because, by default, the request to the pool to get a connection will be queued if none is available. See the docs. Look at the aquireTimeout. Your issue is not releasing the connection https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options

Comment: oh i see the problem now , i thought it was failing but apparently its waiting for a free connection .... thanx

Answer (score 0):

the function pool.getConnection() also requires an allocation pool, you might need add another error handler if this function call fails.